# JSON foreach loop writing data twice to file

Tags: php, json

I am trying to process the JSON response differently based on whether there is just 1 row in the result or more than 1 row.

However, the data being pulled from the result is being written to the file twice.

Can someone see why?

** Added **

```
$module = $_POST['module'];
// Get The Data
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
$row = $obj->response->result->$module->row;
// Count Rows & Fields
$countRows = count($row);
$fields = $obj->response->result->$module->row;
if($countRows == 1)
{
    $row = $obj->response->result->$module->row;
    $countFields = count($row->FL);
    foreach($row as $r) 
    {
         $i = 0;
         foreach($row->FL as $data)
         {
             $i++;
             if($i != $countFields)
             {
                 $csvfile = $module.'.csv';
                 $file = fopen($csvfile, "a");
                 $write = $data->content.',';
                 fwrite($file, $write);
                 fclose($file);
            } 
            else 
            {
                $file = fopen($csvfile, "a");
                $write = $data->content.PHP_EOL;
                fwrite($file, $write);
                fclose($file);
            }
        }
    } 
} else {
        $row = $obj->response->result->$module->row;
        $countFields = count($row[0]->FL);
        foreach($row as $r) 
        {
            $i = 0;
            foreach($r->FL as $data)
            {
                $i++;
                if($i != $countFields)
                {
                $csvfile = $module.'.csv';
                $file = fopen($csvfile, "a");
                $write = $data->content.',';
                fwrite($file, $write);
                fclose($file);
                } else {
                $file = fopen($csvfile, "a");
                $write = $data->content.PHP_EOL;
                fwrite($file, $write);
                fclose($file);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

And what's puzzling me even more is that I'm getting an error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$content

here

```
 $write = $data->content.',';
```

Yet it's writing the data to file *twice* for some unknown reason.

**The error above only occurs on JSON results where there is only 1 record being returned.**

Sample JSON result

```
{
  "response": {
    "result": {
      "Deals": {
        "row": {
          "no": "1",
          "FL": [
            {
              "val": "DEALID",
              "content": "3508588000000206039"
            },
```

Comment: The property `content` does not exist in `$data`.

Comment: Why do you use `foreach($row as $r)` in the scope of the `if($countRows == 1)`? And why you extract it twice?

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @DavidWinder because I've been getting strange errors previously if there was only 1 record in the result hence I added that, plus because of the countfields it wouldnt work on results with 1 row as the JSON result was different so had to add the row[0] to the field count for more than 1 row in result

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Done & nothing other than the error I'm currently getting

Comment: writing each bit to the CSV individually every time you loop is not very efficient (because disk I/O is not very fast compared to RAM). Build a string, and then output it to the file at the end would be better (unless perhaps it's so huge you'd run out of memory or something)

Comment: @ADyson I agree however 3 of the tables I'm working with have over 290'000'000 results with the largest result being pulled having over 319'000'000

Comment: Maybe I missing something but how do you know it written twice if the `content ` is not define? and also notice that you don't write the last `FL` (consider case when only 1 `FL` is exist)

Comment: because I can see 2 entries in the CSV file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `$row` is object and not and array (as can be seen in your example).

It has 2 field: "no" and "FL". So when you loop with `foreach($row as $r)` you will have 2 round (looping on json object).

So now you doing the inner scope twice. Which have:

```
foreach($row->FL as $data) // here referring to base $row
 ...
    $write = $data->content.',';
```

I suggest keep the if `($countRows == 1)` option like this:

```
if($countRows == 1)
{
  $row = $obj->response->result->$module->row;
  $csvfile = $module.'.csv';
  $countFields = count($row->FL);
  $i = 0;
  foreach($row->FL as $data)
  {
      $i++;
      $file = fopen($csvfile, "a");
      $write = $data->content;
      if($i != $countFields)
          $write .= ',';
      else 
          $write .= PHP_EOL;
      fwrite($file, $write);
      fclose($file);
  }
}
```